Adding constraints to a GIST index - postgres
I have created the following index:
ALTER TABLE studio_schedules
      ADD CONSTRAINT overlapping_schedules
      EXCLUDE USING GIST (
        default_studio_id WITH =,
        dynamic_studio_id WITH =,
        tsrange("starts_at_utc", "ends_at_utc", '[)') WITH &&
      );

This works, but I now need to exclude records that do not have a deleted_at timestamp of null.
I've tried a few varieties of:
     ALTER TABLE studio_schedules
      ADD CONSTRAINT overlapping_schedules
      EXCLUDE USING GIST (
        deleted_at = NULL,
        default_studio_id WITH =,
        dynamic_studio_id WITH =,
        tsrange("starts_at_utc", "ends_at_utc", '[)') WITH &&
      );

But all my efforts result in a syntax error.
Can anyone please advise how to ignore records that have a deleted_at timestamp from the index? And where I can view docs on how to structure these indexes? I've not seen this syntax before when writing postgres indexes...
Thanks in advance

You got close, you just needed a WHERE condition in the constraint:
ALTER TABLE studio_schedules
      ADD CONSTRAINT overlapping_schedules
      EXCLUDE USING GIST (
        default_studio_id WITH =,
        dynamic_studio_id WITH =,
        tsrange("starts_at_utc", "ends_at_utc", '[)') WITH &&
      ) WHERE ( deleted_at IS NULL );


@Mark Why do you store the start and end in two different columns? A single tstzrange could do the same and is imho slightly easier because of all the functions and operators you can use without extra casting to a range.

The schedules all have different durations so I think I need to record both the start times and end times, and then see if any other schedules overlap, happy to look at any better alternatives though

That's what a range does, and when looking for overlap and availability, just use one of the many functions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html
